# Index Match search by text or phrase

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&A20&"*",A:A,0)+1)
```

Instead of using "A20", is there a way to make it look for a cell with a word in it?

For example, a cell whose text exactly matches "Order123".

This is probably very simple.  Thank you.

Comment: Just replace the cell reference with the string constant: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("Order123",A:A,0)+1)`

Comment: Thank you so much, lol.  I was trying that but wasn't deleting the asterisks and ampersands.